# Get all class that implement class with specific generic calsses

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to find all classes in my program that implements a given class with a specific call as the generic types.
In the example below would i like to find all classes that implements `MyBaseClass<MyScraper, MyElance>` in this case would it be `MyProperty` and not `OtherProperty` as it implements other generic classes.
How can this be done?

```
public class MyProperty : MyBaseClass<MyScraper, MyElance>
{
    public override string test()
    {
        var test = base.test();
        test += " + the new";
        return test;
    }
}
public class OtherProperty : MyBaseClass<OtherScraper, OtherElance>
{
    public override string test()
    {
        var test = base.test();
        test += " + the other";
        return test;
    }
}

public class MyBaseClass<S, E>
    where S : IScraper
    where E : IElance
{
    public virtual string test()
    {
        return "base";
    }
}
```

Edit:
Found a solution, but please tell me if there are a better way

```
    var test = from x in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).GetTypes()
                                let y = x.BaseType
                                where !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface &&
                                y != null && y.IsGenericType &&
                                y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyBaseClass<,>) &&
                                y.GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(MyScraper) &&
                                y.GenericTypeArguments[1] == typeof(MyElance)
                                select x;
```

Final solution:

```
   var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface)
        .Where(x => x.BaseType != null &&
                    x.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
                    x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (MyBaseClass<,>) &&
                    x.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof (MyScraper) &&
                    x.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[1] == typeof (MyElance))
        .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you already have a working solution.

Comment: It's the best way I know for doing that. Assembly scanning.

Comment: @Servy Or, he could move his solution to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembly scanning is pretty much the best way.

In addition to the algorythm you have, I recommend scanning the `AppDomain` instead of the specific assembly - this will allow you (or others!) toextend your library more readily...

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    //...
```

(Disclaimer Pardon the use of Linq calls here, but I detest syntactical linq)

In addition, make sure any other assemblies are loaded, to ensure you don't miss something at scan-time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//var desiredImplementation = typeof (MyBaseClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof (MyScraper), typeof (MyElance));

var desiredImplementation = typeof (MyBaseClass<MyScraper, MyElance>);

var implementingTypes = Assembly
        .GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(type => desiredImplementation.IsAssignableFrom(type))
        .ToList();
```

You can replace `GetExportedTypes()` with `GetTypes()` and `BindingFlags` to further introspect the assembly too.

Comment: Why not just typeof (MyBaseClass<MyScraper,MyElance>) ?

Comment: There's almost always a follow up question @pil0t. I took a punt that it would be about wanting to be able to pass in the generic types. But yes of course typeof(...) would be simpler and more succinct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchType = typeof(MyBaseClass<MyScraper, MyElance>);
            var types =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    // For search only on assemblies where could exsist this types
                    .Where(a => a.GetName().Name == searchType.Assembly.GetName().Name || a.GetReferencedAssemblies().Any(n => n.Name == searchType.Assembly.GetName().Name))
                    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface)
                    .Select(t => t.GetTypes().Where(a => searchType.IsAssignableFrom(a)))
                    .SelectMany(a => a);
```

I use this version, to search in all loaded assemblies, with additional filter not to process assemblies that could not contain my type